# How to make a UIButton looks like a email link button?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am doing a contact us page. Here I want to add a email link and also I want to open the iPhone's default mail app while clicking that link. I don't know how to make the UIButton looks like a link button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Change the button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`